# Default window shadow dimensions for Snow Leopard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I would like to emulate the default shadow applied to NSWindows with a CALayer shadow. I can't quite figure out the exact values for the the following properties though:

```
theLayer.shadowOffset = ?;
theLayer.shadowRadius = ?;
theLayer.shadowOpacity = ?;
```

I assume that the shadowColor is black (the default).

Does anyone have an idea what those values could be to get a native (Snow) Leopard window shadow?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I'm asking if there's any system API that can give me those values. I don't want to hard code those values, as they have changed in the past and probably will change again at some point in the future.

Answer (score 4):

First, it depends on if a window is in background or in foreground. Windows in foreground have a bigger shadow compared to windows in the background.

For foreground windows you could try the following values:

- Color: black
- X-Offset: 0
- Y-Offset: 4 pixels (downwards)
- Opacity: 100%
- Radius/Blur: 20 pixels

Comment: For the record, they were `black, 0, -8, 80%, 23px` on Tiger! [#funfacts](https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23funfacts)

Comment: And they appear to be about `black, 0, -20, 80%, 45px` on lion (might also just be retina)

Answer (score 3):

A word of warning: the window shadow values have changed before (from Leopard to Snow Leopard), so hardcoding values will likely end up looking off in future OS versions.